# Need steps to configure different domain name for localhost for MAC OSX

Tags: macos, apache

Friends,

I am new to use MAC OS, previously, I used Windows for programming. I need to setup a different name for localhost. I have tried lot of ways but did not work. Need the steps to achieve so.

Things I tried:

1. Add the website name in hosts file by using sudo nano /etc/hosts
2. Add virtual Host information in file placed at location /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
3. Restart Xamp

Answer (score 0):

I found a very good webpage provided the solution, solved the problem for me.

https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite/